# Codeigniter email not working, timeout error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, config, web-hosting

I have set up my new email address to be able to send through my gmail account, using the following details:

[image: google connection]

(i changed the username to keep my domain private)

Using codeigniter here is my config file, before changing hosting services all other email stuff was working fine. (ive updated the from address where the email is sent too)

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'web@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
?>
```

It seems to me it should work, but i keep getting a timeout message. which is never helpful, as it often means i have the wrong details.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk:465 (Connection timed out)
```

---

SSL OPEN is Enabled, as shown in the phpinfo();

[image]

Comment: if you are using gmail for sending email,  you need to change gmail settings to allow less secure app to accesss your account. have you done that?

Comment: @SayantanDas the google configs are only there for comparison,
im attempting to send an email through the smtp server on auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk and was able to connect on googlemail. but the same config in my php doesnt seem to work.

Comment: do you have php_openssl enabled in your .ini file?

Comment: @Sayantan Das im on a shared hosting package, so i dont think i have control over it. But ide presume so, its on a domain with an ssl cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code, and found that my hosting company has all the relevant ports blocked...

Here is some code to find out if you have the same issue i did:

```
   $fp = fsockopen('localhost', 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo('port 80 is closed or blocked.');
    } else {
        echo('port 80 is open and available');
        fclose($fp);
    }
   $fp = fsockopen('localhost', 25, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo('port 25 is closed or blocked.');
    } else {
        echo('port 25 is open and available');
        fclose($fp);
    }
   $fp = fsockopen('localhost', 587, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo('port 587 is closed or blocked.');
    } else {
        echo('port 587 is open and available');
        fclose($fp);
    }
   $fp = fsockopen('localhost', 465, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo('port 465 is closed or blocked.');
    } else {
        echo('port 465 is open and available');
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

responce showed:

```
port 80 is openand available
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:25 (Connection timed out)
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:587 (Connection timed out)
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:465 (Connection timed out)
```